# Reverse geocoding with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I've downloaded us region boundaries from US census bureau, which is a .zip file. I can open to view the file with QGis as follows (4 regions + Alaska):
[image]

Now I have a dataset containing a lot of data point. Each data point has a pair of latitude and longitude. I want to use these numbers to identify which region a data point belongs to.

How can I do it with QGIS?

Comment: Just an FYI to facilitate your own research: this process is not really "reverse geocoding". You're looking for a point-in-polygon style of "spatial join".

Comment: Thank you. yep, it's true. How can I extract polygons corresponding to regions? I have the algorithm to check if a point is inside a polygon

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, MMQGIS plug-in helps me solve the issue. I can now extract polygons, and by using the algorithm from [this site](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/08/point-in-polygon-2-on-line.html), I can make labels for my dataset.